# How to Import/use layouts/GUI from an other class?

Tags: java, swing

I have a main class like this:

```
package ijsberenSpel;

public class Main{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

And I have a layout(gui) class like this:

```
package ijsberenSpel;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Layout extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField textfield;

    public Layout() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        add(label);

        textfield = new JTextField(15);
        add(textfield);

        button = new JButton("Submit");
        add(button);
    }

    public static void layout (String args[]){
        Layout gui = new Layout();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(500, 500);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setTitle("ijsberenspel");
    }
}
```

When I have the code from the layout class in my main class everything works fine, but I want to have the layouts/gui etc, in an other class.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use this :

Create a new Instance of your class:

```
Layout layout = new Layout();
```

Set it visible:

```
layout.setVisible(true);
```

**Note**

```
gui.setVisible(true);
```

Should be after

```
gui.setTitle("ijsberenspel");
```

like this :

```
gui.setTitle("ijsberenspel");
gui.setVisible(true);
```

Also the main method should be like this :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
```

Not

```
public static void layout (String args[]){
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your GUI class:

```
public class Layout extends JFrame {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField textfield;

    public Layout() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);        
        setTitle("ijsberenspel");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        add(label);

        textfield = new JTextField(15);
        add(textfield);

        button = new JButton("Submit");
        add(button);
    } 
}
```

This is your main class with a main method:

```
package ijsberenSpel;

public class Main{    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Layout layout = new Layout();
                layout.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```